# How can I get the value of a key in my JSON data returned from a POST request?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, http

I am trying to get the response from a POST REQUEST. Once I receive my data, I want to find the specific value of the key that I need. The API I am using returns a response in the following format:

```
{
  "id": "STRING",
  "object": "STRING",
  "created": INT,
  "choices": [{
    "index": INT,
    "message": {
      "role": "STRING",
      "content": "STRING",
    },
    "finish_reason": "STRING"
  }],
  "usage": {
    "prompt_tokens": INT,
    "completion_tokens": INT,
    "total_tokens": INT
  }
}
```

I have tried decoding the JSON data returned from the HTTP request. I used Decodable identifiers but it was not able to decode the data. Here is my code:

```swift
let body: [String: Any] = ["model": "gpt-3.5-turbo", "messages": [["role": "user", "content": "hello"]]]
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)

let url = URL(string: "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

request.setValue("Bearer \(API_KEY)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

request.httpBody = jsonData


let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error took place \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    
    if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Use Decodable, not JSONSerialization. You _say_ you "used Decodable" but you didn't. You are not decoding anything; your code receives the data and just stops dead in the water. Add code that decodes it.

Comment: Try www.QuickType.io

Answer (score -1):

As matt said, you are not decoding the data.

To decode:

```
let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(<YOUR_DECODABLE_TYPE>.self, from: data)
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved this issue by creating a custom struct for decoding.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).